# Applications installation

Tags: applications

I can't install vnc viewer for remote control on new elementary loki install. error message can't find file after following instructions from google search

Comment: How did you install it?

Answer (score 1):

you can open a terminal window and run:

```
sudo apt-get install vncviewer
```

However, the package manager will swap it for xtightvncviewer. Haven't used it in about a month, but it's worked well enough for me. Just make sure you have openbox installed on whatever you VNC into.